# Render an animation page THEN redirect to the home page with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, settimeout

Good Afternoon everyone!
I am taking a different approach to my last question. I am trying to implement a loading page animation when visiting the '/' for 3 seconds and then redirect to the home page. I am getting the error that I cant set headers after being sent to the client and I am just not sure on how to get around this. I got the redirect to work, I just dont know how to get the initial render of the animation page.

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');



/* GET home page. */
router.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index-loading-animation')
  setTimeout(function () {
      res.redirect('/')
  }, 3000);
})


module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP just doesn't work like that.

The client makes a request to the server. The server makes a response.

It can say "Here is an HTML document with some animation in it" **or** it can say "What you asked for can be found at this URL instead".

It can't say both because the two statements are contradictory.

If you want to navigate to a new URL when the animation is finished, do so with client side code.

Comment: I found a code snippet that worked. There is a slight hickup when rendering the homepage, but it does work. I am not sure what res.write(html + \n) means, Do you know?   
/* GET home page. */
router.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index-loading-animation', (err,html) => {
    res.write(html + '\n');
    setTimeout(() => {
      res.render('index',  (err,html)=> {
        res.end(html + '\n');
      })
    },5000);
  });
})